# Can MikTeX create tagged PDFs?

Tags: pdf-generation, latex, accessibility, miktex, tagged-pdf

[Tagged PDFs](http://www.planetpdf.com/enterprise/article.asp?ContentID=6067) allow for the easy reflow and accessibility of PDFs. It seems like this would be a natural use case for using LaTeX, which advocates content over style. But as far as I can tell, there is no way to create a tagged PDF with MikTeX 2.8.

Does anybody know of any tips, tricks or techniques to get a tagged PDF through LaTeX without resort to the commercial version of Adobe Acrobat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, well, yes, sort of.

There isn't really sophisticated support for tagging, and what there is, is implemented in pdftex/luatex.  Support for bookmarks and in-document cross-references is done using tagging.  There's also been some more sophisticated work shown at TUG conferences, but this is all in the pipeline for now.

Context/luatex has better support that Latex for this sort of thing: there's some support for interactive documents using Context's layers, where the contents of the layers change when buttons are clicked in the PDF.  I think this must be done using tagging.

I've never heard of anything like embedded forms, digital signing, or embedding the Latex/Tex/Context source in the resulting PDF, but in principle this is all possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same question with pdfLatex in general and found this:

http://sarovar.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=945&group_id=106&atid=495

But I don't test it till now.